# Linux perf and MKL

Tags: openmp, perf, intel-mkl

I've been trying to profile our app (amd64 RHEL 7.6 built with GCC 5.3 and using MKL + OMP). I used perf record, but all I see is a small number of samples in the OMP library. Nothing in main() or below. This is with one 10 minute run and also another that only lasts a second or so.

Is MKL + OMP doing some non-standard threading that perf can't follow?

I'll try running the test and then separately running perf record -p.

Does anyone have experience with perf record and MKL? Maybe VTune will work better!

Comment: The MKL is typically multi-threaded unless you explicitly ask not to be. The computation should be made in computing threads that have they own entry point (ie. not the classical main). The main thread may wait for the other threads to complete resulting in nearly no instruction being executed, at least from the PoV of perf which use a sampling-based method for the profiling (possibly enhanced with hardware event infos). Whether the main thread wait or contribute to the work is implementation defined and the MKL is unfortunately closed-source.

Comment: If you use the MKL in OpenMP parallel section, you may experience over-subscription issues. In that case, it is likely better to use the sequential implementation of the MKL. It make profiling simpler and should also improve performance. It may not if you have load-balancing issue or if your code does not scale but such problem needs to be addressed in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem was with -f(no-)omit-frame-pointer. I was building with -O3 -g3 and for some reason perf record failed to get the stacks. I thought that -g3 would inhibit -fomit-frame-pointer. Presumably MKL still has the frame pointers, so perf could get its stack traces.

Comment: The documentation says nothing about `-g` or `-glevel` changing the behavior of optimization options so I would expect debugging and optimization options to be completely orthogonal. The documentation for `-O1` says "-O also turns on -fomit-frame-pointer on machines where doing so does not interfere with debugging." Whatever that means in detail...